# Proving vector properties 10

Tags: linear-algebra

I had the following question:

Which of the following statements are always true for vectors in $R ^3$

1. If **u** $\cdot($**v** x **w**$) = 4$ then **w** $\cdot($**v** x **u**$)=-4$
2. $(5$**u** + **v**$)$x$($**u** x $7$**v**$) = 36($**u** x **v**$)$
3. If **u** is orthogonal to **v** and **w** then **u** is also orthogonal to ||**w**||**v**+||**v**||**w**

I was able to see which ones were false and which were true by simply plugging in vectors and doing the simple calculations, but I feel like that's not the correct approach. Is there properties in from which these are derived? Or was my approach correct in simply just plugging in to find that 1 and 3 are true.

Comment: To prove any one of the above to be false, you need only supply a counter-example: finding vectors to plug in to find that the statement is not always true.  That's legitimate.  But to prove any one of them correct, you can not justify correctness merely by finding examples that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to prove a result for general vectors $\vec{v},\vec{w}$ using examples won't do.

On the other hand, when you have to verify that a rule is non-correct, then finding an example is indeed the way to go.

For the first exercise you need to use the [property of the triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Properties) which indeed shows that the result is true.

For the second case, just notice that by linearity of the cross product:
\begin{align*}(5u+v)\times (u+7v)&=5u\times u+5u\times 7v+v\times u+v\times 7v\\
&=0+35u\times v+v\times u+0\\ &=35u\times-u\times v\\& =34u\times v\end{align*}
so in general the result is non correct (just take any two vectors whose cross product is non-vanishing).

For the third, orthogonality means:
$$\langle u,v\rangle=0\quad \langle u,w\rangle=0$$
but by the linearity of the scalar product in the second component
$$\langle u,\|w\|v+\|v\|w\rangle=\|w\|\langle u,v\rangle+\|v\|\langle u,w\rangle=0$$
which is equivalent to the statement of orthogonality

Comment: Thank you, that really helps!